# Log report software for ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a node ELK (elasticsearch-logstash-kibana), and i need save report and statistics of logs, there is software that does this?
I have found other dashboard for elasticsearch but are all similar to kibana and not save report (packetbeat, elasticsearch-monitoring etc...)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this github thread](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/303#issuecomment-58086110) you can save the results of a chart into **CSV**.

From there, it's easy to use MS Excel or some other tool to create a report.

I think is as far as you can go with *free* tools.

**p.s.:** [this](https://github.com/robbydyer/stash-query) seems to be another option but it looks like it only dumps the result, not produce reports like you want.